# Significato di "tirare in piedi i baracconi del sottogoverno"

Tags: meaning

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> Ma quale riforma? A parte qualche aggiustamento poco risolutivo, le uniche riforme di spicco che
>   hanno partorito sono quelle per **tirare in piedi i baracconi del sottogoverno**... Le riforme per liberare delinquenti in massa, la salvaladri per togliere di galera i pezzi da
>   novanta della truffa e dell’intrallazzo. Le riforme per aumentarsi lo stipendio fra onorevoli e senatori, anche se
>   condannati per corruzione e furto...

Non capisco del tutto bene il significato dell'espressione "tirare in piedi i baracconi del sottogoverno" che appare in questo passaggio. Ho cercato il termine ["baraccone" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000054.jpg), ma immagino che in questo testo abbia un senso figurato (non credo faccia veramente riferimento a una "baracca di  grandi dimen­sioni" come quelle delle fiere). Per quanto riguarda il vocabolo "sottogoverno", che non conoscevo, ho trovato il suo significato sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000600.jpg) e [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000601.jpg). Non ho trovato invece cosa vuol dire la locuzione "tirare in piedi", malgrado averla cercata alla voce "piede" di parecchi dizionari: è lo stesso che "mettere in piedi", cioè, secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piede/), "allestire, preparare"?

Comunque, la mia domanda riguarda il senso di "tirare in piedi i baracconi del sottogoverno": il significato potrebbe essere mettere in piedi le attività di favoritismo e corruzione svolte dall'amministrazione pubblica di cui parla il GDLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per il significato di baraccone, prendo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/baraccone/):

> Fig., organismo, istituzione (pubblica o privata) di struttura troppo complessa, caotica, mal funzionante, in cui c’è disordine e confusione

È corretta la tua deduzione sul significato di *"tirare in piedi"* nel senso di *"mettere in piedi"*, *"allestire"* e anche il significato di sottogoverno da te riportato è corretto (e simile a quello riportato [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sottogoverno/)).

Il significato del brano significa proprio quindi che le riforme di cui si parla hanno avuto come unico risultato quello di allestire delle strutture di sottogoverno improduttive, e che perseguono come unico scopo la perpetuazione del proprio potere (tramite favoritismi, corruzione, ecc).